# pyqtgraph: How to color plot axis?

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

I have tried to color the axis of a pyqtgraph plot in the following line

```
self.PlotWidget.setLabel('bottom', '...')
```

but this just colors the text from the label.

[image]

So my question is, is there a possibility to color just the black background of the plot?

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Check this out: https://pythonspot.com/pyqt5-colors/

Comment: Thank you very much, i had a faulty reasoning. I just had to set the background color.

Comment: How did you manage to get the axis colour to be green and the background to be black? This is exactly what I want however I can only find the background colour to change.